# I'm voting to close this tag as off-topic because it's about [piano], not programming

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

Believe it or not, yes, we do have a [piano](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/piano) tag, which has the following very off-topic description:

> The piano (an abbreviation of pianoforte) is a musical instrument played using a keyboard.

This clearly has nothing whatsoever to do with programming.

While a lot of the questions that use this are about programming somehow, there's little commonality in what they're actually *about* (beyond that they have something to do with the piano). They're about everything from GUI elements to JavaScript to digital signal processing.

Can this be burninated?

Comment: I don't see how this tag is problematic. Granted, there are some off-topic questions that currently have the tag, but asking about topics related to programming and pianos seems to be relatively commonplace, and it is useful to have some semantic way of organizing those posts.

Comment: @CodyGray perhaps, but I'm not sure we need separate tags for [piano], [virtual-keyboard], and [synthesizer] (any programming-relevant question about a piano is almost surely going to be actually about a synthesizer or some on-screen piano keys). Actually looking closer it seems that [virtual-keyboard] use I noticed is a misuse as it's about on-screen keyboard maps, not virtual pianos.

Comment: @TylerH So [synthesizer] for programming questions about a physical instrument [virtual-piano] for programming an on screen piano, and retagging questions misusing virtual-keyboard? (Maybe even [virtual-musical-instrument]? Does the specific instrument matter?) Oh, and fixing the usage guidance and info.

Comment: @BSMP I imagine there are some differences between virtual pianos and virtual trumpets... but I'm not really an expert on programming for musical instruments. The suggestions you made sound good to me, though.

Comment: How can I program with my left foot which is left doing nothing while I'm playing the piano? Tags -- [tag:Piano], [tag:Keypress], [tag:FootAble].